# Barney DeVine Circus Performer from Ireland 1800-1860

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, ireland

I'm looking for any information someone might have regarding Barney DeVine who was a circus performer in Ireland and came to the US around 1834.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than "for any information".  How do you know that Barney "came to the US around 1834"?  Is it an immigration record that you seek first?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Barney DeVine who arrived in New York aboard the Howard in 1834. The [passenger list](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:939V-PQ9S-JH?i=95&wc=MX62-GM9%3A165725001%3Fcc%3D1849782&cc=1849782), on FamilySearch, states his age to be 21 and place of birth as Ireland.

His occupation, slightly obscured by what appears to be an ink blot, is given as "labourer".

---

Just to make life interesting, there is also a B DeVine, aged 22 and born in Ireland, who arrived in New York [on board the Eagle](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:939V-5T7N-K?i=384&wc=MX62-LM3%3A165725801%3Fcc%3D1849782&cc=1849782) in 1934. His occupation was also given as "labourer".